# Android Studio Beginner;

Tags: java, android-studio

So here's my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        /* access modifiers changed from: protected */
        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent;
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.button: // Text
                    intent = new Intent(this,"Faiz Ahmed \nLove music forever\nTCSS 450");
                    break;
                case R.id.button2: // Image
                    intent = new Intent(this, ImageActivity.class);
                    break;
                case R.id.button3: // Web
                    intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW");
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://developer.android.com"));
                    break;
                case R.id.button4: // Toast
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Here's to a new quarter!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                    break;
                case R.id.button5: // Dialog
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                    builder.setMessage("I am a dialog").setTitle("Some Title").create().show();
            }
            intent = null;
            if (intent != null) {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

---

All the import's are there I just for some reason none of the buttons are working. The first 2 (Text & Image) I know I need a lot more code, but the last 3 should work & they're not for some reason. Any know what I'm doing wrong & how to fix it?

Comment: intent is always null, you can add a default branch in the switch statement to set intent to null. The way the code is set up now, no what matter what happens in the switch statement, you set intent to null so startActivity is never called

Comment: You need to handle when you don't need the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing of the buttons will work because in the switch-case statement you initialize the `intent` according to which button was pressed.

After that **you set `intent` to null** and lastly you start the activity if the intent is not null, but it always is (since you set it before to null).

Short story **delete `intent = null;`** statement.

```
// intent = null; delete this line
if (intent != null) {
 startActivity(intent);
}
```